# Create a bash command java

Tags: java, bash, unix, terminal

I have a java file called 'move.class' I want to make it into a bash command so people can call it from the bash terminal, input options or parameters, and read its manual page:

People should be able to use this like any other command:

```
$ sudo move | more
```

I need to read the arguments and parameters (in java)

```
$ move -i --string=HELLO file1 fil2
```

I also need it to have a man page so a user can say:

```
$ man move
```

To get comprehensive instructions on how to use this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create shell script `move`. Something like following:

`java -cp yourjar.jar com.yourcompany.move.Main $*`

Put this script to location that is in the path of most users. For example `/sbin`.

Now the command should work. 
This is the time to refer to [this](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/creatingman.htm)  or similar tutorial that explains how to create man pages.

Comment: Agreed, and I think the `| more` will take whatever you output by using `System.out.println()`

Comment: He would probably want "$@" (quoted) as $* would not work with args that contain a space.

Answer (score 0):

id suggest using the alias command. Something like

```
alias move="java yourClass"
```